# Show that the tangents in $x=a$ to the solutions $y$ of $y' +g(x)y = h(x)$ all have a common point

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $a$ be a real number, $g$ and $h$ be continuous functions such that $g(a)\neq 0$

To every solution curve $y(x)$ to the differential equation $y' + g(x)y = h(x)$ a tangent is drawn in the curves intersection point with $x=a$. Show that all these tangents has a common point and determine this point.

I am not able to solve this. I have managed to get the correct answer to the $x$-value in the common point but am not able to see how the $y$-value of the common point can be the same for all solution curves. This is my approach so far:

Let the common point be $P = (x_p, y_p)$.
Since $g, h$ are continuous they have antiderivatives $G, H$. Therefore
$y' + g(x)y = h(x) \iff \frac{d}{dx} ye^{G(x)} = e^{G(x)}h(x)$
$e^{G(x)}h(x)$ is continuous so it has an antiderivative $K(x)$. So
$ye^{G(x)} = K(x) + C \iff y = \dfrac{K(x)}{e^{G(x)}} + \dfrac{C}{e^{G(x)}} = K_2(x) + \dfrac{C}{e^{G(x)}}$

And $y' = K_2'(x) - \dfrac{Cg(x)}{e^{G(x)}}$

First I try to determine $x_p$:
If two solution curves with different constants have the same value this would mean that

$K_2(a) + \dfrac{C_1}{e^{G(a)}} + \left(K_2'(a) - \dfrac{C_1g(a)}{e^{G(a)}}\right)(x-a) =\\
K_2(a) + \dfrac{C_2}{e^{G(a)}} + \left(K_2'(a) - \dfrac{C_2g(a)}{e^{G(a)}}\right)(x-a) \iff$

$\left(g(a)\dfrac{C_2 - C_1}{e^{G(a)}} \right)(x-a) = \dfrac{C_2-C_1}{e^{G(a)}} \iff$

$x-a = \dfrac{1}{g(a)} \iff x = a + \dfrac{1}{g(a)}$

According to my book this answer for $x_p$ is correct. <s>However, I cannot see how there could exist a $y_p$ since</s>

$y_1(x) = y_2(x) \iff K_2(x) + \dfrac{C_1}{e^{G(x)}} = K_2(x) + \dfrac{C_2}{e^{G(x)}} \iff C_1 = C_2$
which of course is not true for all constants $C_1, C_2$.

Edit: Nevermind this last part, I'm not comparing tangents.

According to the book $y_p = \dfrac{h(a)}{g(a)}$. I feel like I have done some big mistakes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tangent at $x=a$ has the equation
$$
t(x)=y(a)+y'(a)(x-a)=y(a)+(h(a)-g(a)y(a))(x-a)=y(a)[1-g(a)(x-a)]+h(a)(x-a).
$$
This tangent has a point that is independent of the value $y(a)$ when $1=g(a)(x-a)$, that is, at $x_a=a+\frac1{g(a)}$, with value $t(x_a)=\frac{h(a)}{g(a)}$.